# Command to detect if elastic search is active in linux

Tags: linux, elasticsearch

I have to detect if `elastic search` is running on Linux. If it is not running than start it machine using `shell script`.
Used following code to detect if elastic search is running, but every time else condition is executed even if service is running:

```
service=elasticsearch

if (( $(ps -ef | grep -v grep | grep $service | wc -l) > 0 ))
then
echo "$service is running!!!"
else
echo "$service is not running!!!"
fi
```

Comment: should asked on http://askubuntu.com/

Comment: I don't see a problem with your `if` test, but did you try just running inner cmds? i.e. `ps -ef | grep $service`? Do you get any reasonable output from that? If not then you need to regroup and figure out what is going on. Good luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a sample script and used in a shell script to check if my sevice is running:

Take a look at this script to see if it helps you.

```
#verify if the service is running   
ps aux | grep SERVICENAME | pidof java > /dev/null
verifier=$?
zero=0
if [ $zero = $verifier ]
then
    echo "Service was successfully started"
else
    echo "Service stopped"
fi
```

In my case my service was done in java then I use the pidof to properly filter my service

Answer (score 0):

The issue with checking for pid is that the service might have started, but it might not be ready actually. So instead, I check for port that ES is listening on.  It works better for me.

```
netstat -uplnt | grep :9200 | grep LISTEN > /dev/null
verifier=$?
if [ 0 = $verifier ]
    then
        echo "ES is listening on port 9200"
    else
        echo "ES is not ready yet"
fi
```